# How can I get input value to work in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript and trying to create something today. I have a text box, submit button and a hidden p tag called "demo". I want user to enter either number or text. If the user enter number it will then do one thing and if user text it will do another thing. Please see the code (any input will help...):

```
            <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Practice.aspx.cs" Inherits="Javascript.Javascript.Practice" %>

            <!DOCTYPE html>

            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head runat="server">
                <title></title>
                <script>
                    function takeAction(){
                        var x = document.getElementById("textId").value;
                       // var y = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=("You entered "+x + ".");
                        if (x == Number) {
                            function numberFunction() {
                                switch (x) {
                                    case 1:
                                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("You entered " + x + " and your number is 1.");
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("You entered " + x + " and your number is 2.");
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("You entered " + x + " and your number is not between 1 & 2.");
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (x == Text) {
                                function textFunction() {
                                    switch (x) {
                                        case "John":
                                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("You are " + x + " and you are number 1 position.");
                                            break;
                                        case "Chris":
                                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("You are " + x + " and you are number 2 position.");
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("You are " + x + " and you are number not a member.");
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        }
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form id="form1" runat="server">
                    <div>
                        <label>Please enter something: </label>
                        <input type="text" id="textId" />
                        <button id="btn" onclick="takeAction()">Submit</button><b />

                        <p id="demo"></p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Change if conditions, if (typeof x === "number") and if (typeof x === "string")

Comment: Use `if (IsNaN(x)) { //not a number }`  - The `== Number` comparison makes no sense (assuming your trying to compare against the type) - For text reverse `IsNaN()` (The type of a `.value` will most often be a `String` irrespective of its composition)

Comment: Where are you actually calling these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use like this

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" >
  <div>
    <label>Please enter something: </label>
    <input type="text" id="textId" />
    <button id="btn" onclick="takeAction()">Submit</button><b />
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function takeAction() {
   var x = document.getElementById('textId').value;

   function numberFunction(number) {
     var y = number;
     switch (parseInt(y)) {
       case 1:
         document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ("You entered " + y + " and your number is 1.");
         break;
       case 2:
         document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ("You entered " + y + " and your number is 2.");
         break;
       default:
         document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ("You entered " + y + " and your number is not between 1 & 2.");
         break;
     }
   }

   function textFunction(text) {
     var y = text;
     switch (y) {
       case "John":
         document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ("You are " + y + " and you are number 1 position.");
         break;
       case "Chris":
         document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ("You are " + y + " and you are number 2 position.");
         break;
       default:
         document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ("You are " + y + " and you are number not a member.");
         break;

     }
   }
   if (isNaN(x)) {
     textFunction(x);
   } else {
     numberFunction(x);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Text are working fine but the number are displaying default case "You entered 1 and your number is not between 1 & 2."

Comment: Perfect! @Praveen Raj.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I have done it in the past

```
var validNumbers = "0123456789";
var number = true
for(var i = 0;i<x.length;i++){
    character = x.charAt(i); 
    if (validNumbers.indexOf(character) == -1){
        number = false;
    }
}
if(number) {
    //It is a number
}
else {
    //It isn't a number
}
```

Here is where I got the code from I was trying to do a similar thing to you. (sorry about the lack of indentation):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Exam entry</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var number = true;
var validNumbers = "0123456789";
var character;
function validateForm() {
var result = true;
var msg="";

if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
msg+="You must enter your name \n";
document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
result = false;
}
if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
result = false;
}
number = true
for(var i = 0;i<document.ExamEntry.examNumber.value.length;i++){
character = document.ExamEntry.examNumber.value.charAt(i); 
if (validNumbers.indexOf(character) == -1){
number = false;
}
}
if (document.ExamEntry.examNumber.value.length != 4||number==false){
msg+="You must enter your examination number correctly \n";
document.ExamEntry.examNumber.focus();
document.getElementById('examNumber').style.color="red";
result = false;
}
if(msg==""){
return result;
}
{
alert(msg)
return result;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
<table width="50%" border="0">
<tr>
<td id="name">Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="subject">Subject</td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="examNumber">Examination Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="examNumber" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
<td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not see any changes.

Comment: Many apologies I forget the most important bit you need to declare a string 'var validNumbers = "0123456789";'

Comment: Not working, here's the first part of the code before if else: function takeAction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("textId").value;
            var number = true;
            var validNumbers = "0123456789";
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                character = x.charAt(i);
                if (validNumbers.indexOf(character) == -1) {
                    number = false;
                }
            }

Comment: you may have to declare `var character;` at the beginning.

Comment: What results are you actually getting. Are you sure the takeAction() function gets called?

Comment: Well, whenever I am clicking on the submit button, it is doing something but not the message/text I want to see. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/anam/39rm86r1/